# Compare two sheets and highlight differences on each sheet - is looping the only way?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, performance, loops

I am seeking advice in relation to improving performance for a large data set (roughly 175k lines on each sheet and 39 columns A:AM (comparing sheet1 vs sheet2). These sheets are exported from access and my VBA is written in Access. I have coding that employs a "for" loop that checks cell by cell and highlights if there is a mismatch in each relative cell.

My question - will using an array or dictionary function speed up the process? If yes, can you provide bread crumbs to shed some light on how to execute? This code currently takes approximately 3 hours to complete. Roughly 2 minutes for the export from Access to Excel and the rest of the time represents looping and highlighting.

As a note - I have written code for conditional formatting and that works incredibly fast. The main problem is that I am unable to copy/paste the sheets with highlighted cells into new sheets while leaving the conditions behind. I would be interested to hear if any have found a way to maneuver that mine field.

Code below:

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

            Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
            Dim xlbook As Excel.Workbook
            Dim xlSheet, xlSheetPre, xlSheetPost As Excel.Worksheet
            Dim SQL As String
            Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
            Dim iSheet As Long, iRow As Long, iCol As Long, cols As Long
            Dim MaxLastRow As Long, MaxLastCol As Long
            Dim LastRow1 As Range, LastRow2 As Range
            Dim LastCol1 As Range, LastCol2 As Range
            Dim i As Integer
            

            SQL = "SELECT * From Pre"
            
            Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
            Set xlapp = Excel.Application
                xlapp.Visible = True
            Set xlbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Add
                i = 1
            Do
                Set xlSheet = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
                i = i + 1
            Loop Until i = 2 ' the number 2 represents how many sheets you want to add to the 
            workbook
            
            Set xlSheet = xlbook.Worksheets(1) ' Finds worksheet (1) and begins loading data from SQL 
            table above
            
            With xlSheet
            .Name = "Pre" ' Name the worksheet
            .Range("a1:am1").Font.Bold = True 'Converts headers in row 1 to 
             bold font
            .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs1 'Copies all data from selected 
             table (SQL)into your worksheet
            .Range("a1").AutoFilter ' Adds filter to your columns
            .Cells.Columns.AutoFit ' Adjust worksheet column width to autofit 
             your data
            .Range("a1:am1").Interior.ColorIndex = 37 ' Changes color of cell
            ' This loop reads all headers in your access table and places 
             them on worksheet
            For cols = 0 To rs1.Fields.Count - 1
                .Cells(1, cols + 1).Value = rs1.Fields(cols).Name
            Next
            
            
            End With
            
            SQL = "SELECT * From Post"
            Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
            Set xlSheet = xlbook.Worksheets(2)
            
            With xlSheet
            .Name = "Post" ' Name the worksheet
            .Range("a1:am1").Font.Bold = True 'Converts headers in row 1 to 
             bold font
            .Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs1 'Copies all data from selected 
             table (SQL)into your worksheet
            .Range("a1").AutoFilter ' Adds filter to your columns
            .Cells.Columns.AutoFit ' Adjust worksheet column width to autofit 
             your data
            .Range("a1:am1").Interior.ColorIndex = 37 ' Changes color of cell
            ' This loop reads all headers in your access table and places 
             them on worksheet
            ' This loop reads all headers in your access table and places them on worksheet
            For cols = 0 To rs1.Fields.Count - 1
            .Cells(1, cols + 1).Value = rs1.Fields(cols).Name
            Next

            
            End With
            
            Set xlSheetPre = xlbook.Worksheets(1)
            Set xlSheetPost = xlbook.Worksheets(2)
            
            Set LastRow1 = xlSheetPre.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            Set LastRow2 = xlSheetPost.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            
            If Not LastRow1 Is Nothing Then
                If Not LastRow2 Is Nothing Then
                    If LastRow1.Row > LastRow2.Row Then
                        MaxLastRow = LastRow1.Row
                    Else
                        MaxLastRow = LastRow2.Row
                    End If
                Else
                    MaxLastRow = LastRow1.Row
                End If
            Else
                MaxLastRow = LastRow2.Row
            End If
            
            Set LastCol1 = xlSheetPre.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            Set LastCol2 = xlSheetPost.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            
            If Not LastCol1 Is Nothing Then
                If Not LastCol2 Is Nothing Then
                    If LastCol1.Column > LastCol2.Column Then
                        MaxLastCol = LastCol1.Column
                    Else
                        MaxLastCol = LastCol2.Column
                    End If
                Else
                    MaxLastCol = LastCol1.Column
                End If
            Else
                MaxLastCol = LastCol2.Column
            End If
            
            For iRow = 2 To MaxLastRow 'starting loop on row 2
                For iCol = 4 To MaxLastCol 'starting loop on column 4
                    If xlSheetPre.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value <> xlSheetPost.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value Then
                    xlSheetPre.Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                    xlSheetPost.Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            
                    End If
                    
                Next iCol
            Next iRow
            
            SubExit:
            On Error Resume Next
            
            rs1.Close
            Set rs1 = Nothing
            DoCmd.SetWarnings True
            
            Exit Sub
```

Comment: Your code only puts the headers in the Excel sheets?  Where's the data?  Your code will run much faster if you load the data into arrays and compare the arrays: cell-by-cell data access is relatively slow.

Comment: Also not clear how `LastRow1` etc could be `Nothing` - you already wrote the headers to the sheet, so that should never happen.

Comment: Thanks for calling that out. I left out my formatting lines and looks like I removed too much initially. With the LastRow1/2, my thought was to say if LastRow1 is different than LastRow2, adjust the sheet that has less so all comparisons are 1 to 1 between sheets.

Comment: Do the pre and post tables share a common primary key ?

Comment: Yes, column A has a key that is aligned (a1 on pre = a1 on post) in Access before export to Excel. If Pre has a key that post does not then the Pre key will be highlighted.

Comment: I'm assuming the number of differences is relatively small in which case see how long a single field query takes where prev.field1 <> post.field1 . If that takes a few seconds just repeat 39 times. Or compare 3 fields in the query and repeat 13 times.

Comment: I would say each column 4-39 will have a couple of hundred differences to highlight. In using prev.field1<>post.field1 strategy, would that highlight the entire field if differences are found? I am trying to think through what the "Then" statement would be to capture the individual cell with the difference.

Comment: Are you able to create a temporary table in the database ?

Comment: Temp Table in Access? Yes. With some details removed - the process is to import (into Access) file 1, import file 2, and then align the key in field 1 of both files. File 1 becomes “Pre” and file 2 becomes “Post”. Pre and Post are then exported to Excel.

Comment: What format is your "raw" data (the data you import to Access?)  It might be simpler to perform the comparison directly on those files.  Or if you want to stay with access for the initial part, open two recordsets and perform the comparison on those directly instead of first dumping the data to Excel.

Comment: Both raw data files are excel. The problem with the raw data file is that columns are not always lined up and calculations and comparisons need to take place via Access queries before we get to the final result. Can you help me understand how to load the data into arrays and then compare arrays? My experience in VBA is relative minimal and haven't been able to piece together comparing an array of Pre vs array of Post.

Answer (score 0):

Try and reduce the number of records you have to compare by only extracting those with differences. There are several ways you could do that in SQL but as a proof of concept this compares each column in turn creating a temporary table of keys which is used to filter the records extracted.

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub DumpToExcel()

    Dim n As Integer, SQL As String, fname
    ' field names
    fname = Array("", "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5", _
                  "F6", "F7", "F8", "F9", "F10")

    ' identify diff records
    Debug.Print UBound(fname)
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    For n = 1 To UBound(fname)
        If n = 1 Then ' create table
            SQL = " SELECT post.ID, """ & n & """ AS Col INTO tmp"
        Else
            SQL = " INSERT INTO tmp" & _
                  " SELECT post.ID, """ & n & """ AS Col"
        End If
        SQL = SQL & _
            " FROM Post LEFT JOIN pre ON Post.id = pre.id" & _
            " WHERE NZ([pre].[" & fname(n) & "],"")<>NZ([post].[" & fname(n) & "],"");"
        
        DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

    Next
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    ' extract data
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset

    SQL = " SELECT * FROM pre" & _
          " WHERE (((pre.[ID]) In " & _
          " (SELECT DISTINCT(ID) FROM tmp )));"

    Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

    ' create excel
    Dim xlapp As Excel.Application, xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Set xlapp = Excel.Application
    xlapp.Visible = True
    Set xlBook = xlapp.Workbooks.Add
    
    'add sheets as required
    Do While xlBook.Sheets.Count < 2
        xlBook.Sheets.Add
    Loop

    ' copy recordset to sheet
    xlBook.Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs1
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I did a quick copy of the coding but am getting pop up boxes with "Enter parameter value - "Post.ID", followed by "pre.id". I will review this code to see if I can make sense of it and let you know.

Comment: @Erik Change ID to whatever your primary key field is

Answer (score 0):

Here's an array-based comparison.

Compiled but not tested:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet, wsPre As Excel.Worksheet, wsPost As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rowsPost As Long, rowsPre As Long, rowsMax As Long
    Dim colsPre As Long, colsPost As Long, colsMax As Long, flag As Boolean
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, rngPre As Range, rngPost As Range, arrPre, arrPost
    
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    
    Set xlapp = New Excel.Application 'forgot "New" here?
    xlapp.Visible = True
    Set xlbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Add()
    Do While xlbook.Worksheets.Count < 2 'how many sheets you need in the Workbook
        xlbook.Sheets.Add
    Loop
    
    Set wsPre = xlbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set wsPost = xlbook.Worksheets(2)
    
    PutInWorksheet "SELECT * From Pre", wsPre, "Pre"
    PutInWorksheet "SELECT * From Post", wsPost, "Post"
    
    Set rngPre = wsPre.Range("A1").CurrentRegion   'data ranges
    Set rngPost = wsPost.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    arrPre = rngPre.Value   'read data to arrays
    arrPost = rngPost.Value
    
    rowsPre = UBound(arrPre, 1) 'compare array bounds...
    rowsPost = UBound(arrPost, 1)
    rowsMax = xlapp.Max(rowsPre, rowsPost)
    
    colsPre = UBound(arrPre, 2)
    colsPost = UBound(arrPost, 2)
    colsMax = xlapp.Max(colsPre, colsPost)
    
    For r = 2 To rowsMax
        flag = (r > rowsPre) Or (r > rowsPost) 'flag whole row if have run out of data in one set...
        If flag Then
            FlagRanges rngPre.Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, colsMax), _
                       rngPost.Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, colsMax)
        Else
            'have two rows to compare
            For c = 1 To colsMax
                flag = (c > colsPre) Or (c > colsPost) 'run out of cols in one dataset?
                If Not flag Then
                    flag = arrPre(r, c) <> arrPost(r, c) 'compare data
                End If
                If flag Then
                    'no data to compare, or data does not match
                    FlagRanges rngPre.Cells(r, c), rngPost.Cells(r, c)
                End If
            Next c
        End If
    Next r
End Sub

Sub FlagRanges(rng1 As Excel.Range, rng2 As Excel.Range)
    Const CLR_INDX = 4
    rng1.Interior.ColorIndex = CLR_INDX
    rng2.Interior.ColorIndex = CLR_INDX
End Sub

'run a query and put the results on a worksheet starting at A1
Sub PutInWorksheet(SQL As String, ws As Excel.Worksheet, _
    Optional newName As String = "")
    Dim f, c As Excel.Range, rs As dao.Recordset
    
    If Len(newName) > 0 Then ws.Name = newName
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
    Set c = ws.Range("A1")
    For Each f In rs.Fields
        c.Value = f.Name
        c.Font.Bold = True
    Next f
    ws.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Tim. One question, when I compile I get flagged with a Compile error:" method or data member not found." for "rowsMax = Application.Max(rowsPre, rowsPost)". Is this a tool>reference issue?

Comment: to be more specific the **.Max** is taking the error.

Comment: Sorry I was writing in excel so you’d need xlapp.Max

Comment: Great, xlApp.Max solved for the compile error. It appears I am running into one more issue in the Sub PutInWorksheet: "For each f In rs1.fields" is stating an object is required.

Comment: For each f in rs.fields

Comment: Made a couple additional fixes - edited code above...

Comment: The edited code above worked smoothly. I took a round number of 5k rows and compared against my original code. Using the array reduced the time by 25%. Thank you for providing the code!

Answer (score 0):

*"My question - will using an array or dictionary function speed up the process?"*

Speaking from experience, the answer is: ***No, it will not***. The reason is that you will have to read the cells in the worksheet to populate an array or a dictionary in the first place, so... Looping is it, really, and you need to organize the data (usually by proper sorting of the lists, tables, ranges, whatever) to minimize searching for the matching records (rows) to make your loops run faster.

If you are in Access then you can do that directly with the recordsets, providing your company's network security does not interfere with movement withing recordset objects (mine does interfere, and very severely at that--Tanium is a real menace!)

Comment: Speaking from my experience - if you were performing a nested loop to compare records - using a dictionary would be much faster.  It's true that there's some overhead to loading the dictionary, but avoiding the nested loop is well worth that.

Comment: @TimWilliams: How do you store records with multiple fields with multiple data types in a dictionary?

Comment: Is there any advantage to using dictionary vs array?

Comment: @Erik_U  -- they are different, it depends on what you need and what the data is; google both and see for yourself, please.

Comment: You can store any data type in the Value of a dictionary entry, but when used in this "avoid nested loop" scenario it typically is just a row index pointing to the row number in an array